# Drag and Drop - Moving a Label in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I've created a label override that will allow my new control to be moved around the screen easily.

I've attached the code below, but when I run the application or attempt to move the label it's always off. It also will sometimes just completely vanish, leave a trail or reset to the 0,0 location. Have a look at the screenshot.

I used to have this working 100%, but after some recent tweaking it has gone to the dogs again and I'm not sure how to get it working.

**Screenshot:**
[image: Attempting to Drag]

**Code:**

```
internal sealed class DraggableLabel : Label
{

    private bool _dragging;
    private int _mouseX, _mouseY;

    public DraggableLabel()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
      if (_dragging)
        {
            Point mposition = PointToClient(MousePosition);
            mposition.Offset(_mouseX, _mouseY);

            Location = mposition;
        }
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
           _dragging = true;
           _mouseX = -e.X;
           _mouseY = -e.Y;
           BringToFront();
           Invalidate();
        }
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_dragging)
        {
            _dragging = false;
            Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle();
            Invalidate();
        }

        base.OnMouseUp(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: this goes to show that you __should be using [version control](http://www.fortnet.org/FortNet/HTML/Presentation/CVS/whyvc.html)__ to prevent such things from happening in the future. [This tutorial](http://hginit.com/01.html) might help you get started.

Comment: that sounds very different than `I used to have this working 100%, but after some recent tweaking it has gone to the dogs again` - as you can see, it wouldn't have hurt to mention that in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OnMouseMove() code is bad.  Do it like this instead:

```
private Point lastPos;

protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
        int dx = e.X - lastPos.X;
        int dy = e.Y - lastPos.Y;
        Location = new Point(Left + dx, Top + dy);
        // NOTE: do NOT update lastPos, the relative mouse position changed
    }
    base.OnMouseMove(e);
}

protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
        lastPos = e.Location;
        BringToFront();
        this.Capture = true;
    }
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}

protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e) {
    this.Capture = false;
    base.OnMouseUp(e);
}
```

The screen shot also shows evidence of the form not redrawing properly.  You didn't leave any clue as to what might cause that.

Comment: That's it! Thanks heaps!. Yeah looking at it now I can see a few things I should have done differently!

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this recently, and I solved it by setting the background color of the label to `Color.Transparent`.

If this doesn't solve it, then you should consider monitoring your event handling. It could be that you're registering more than one mouse move event and thus each method would interfere with the other.

**EDIT :**

Have you also tried overriding the OnPaint method of its parent class?

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pe);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should put focus on your element like

```
label1.Focus();
```