MouseMove event work with jump between two location?
I wrote a class for labels that I want to be able to move and resize at runtime with the mouse.
This is easily done by adding three mouse events (label.MouseDown, label.MouseUp, label.MouseMove)
MouseDown :: When the mouse button goes down, based on the location of the mouse (it is on the edge of the label or inside it), it determines whether the target is moving or resizing, and it is stored in two variables (_moving, _resizing).
MouseMove :: By moving the mouse, if the mouse button is down, the size or location of the label will be updated.
MouseUp :: When the mouse button is upend, the variables are false.
public class Ulabel
{
public System.Windows.Forms.Label label;

        public UTask(string title, Color color, int Lno)
        {
            label = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            label.Text = title;
            label.BackColor = color;
            label.Name = "T" + Lno.ToString();
            label.AutoSize = false;
            label.Size = new Size(20, 50);
            label.Location = new Point(50, 50);
            Init();
        }

private bool _moving;
private bool _resizing;

private Point _cursorStartPoint;
private Point _cursorStartPointmove;
private Point _cursorLast;
private int _Initwidth;

private bool MouseIsInRightEdge;
       
int count_call = 0;

internal void Init()
{
    _moving = false;
    _resizing = false;
    _moveIsInterNal = false;
    _cursorStartPoint = Point.Empty;
    _cursorStartPointmove = Point.Empty;

    MouseIsInRightEdge = false;

    label.MouseDown += (sender, e) => MouseDown(label, e);
    label.MouseUp += (sender, e) => MouseUp(label);
    label.MouseMove += (sender, e) => MouseMove(label, e);
}

private void UpdateMouseEdgeProperties(Control control, Point mouseLocationInControl)
{
    MouseIsInRightEdge = Math.Abs(mouseLocationInControl.X - control.Width) <= 4;
}

private void UpdateMouseCursor(Control control)
{
    if (MouseIsInRightEdge)
        control.Cursor = Cursors.SizeWE;

    else
        control.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}

private void MouseDown(Control control, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (_moving || _resizing)
        return;

    if (MouseIsInRightEdge)
    {
        _resizing = true;
        _moving = false;
        _Initwidth = control.Width;
    }
    else
    {
        _moving = true;
        _resizing = false;
        control.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll;
        _cursorStartPointmove = new Point(e.X - control.Left, e.Y - control.Top);
    }
    _cursorStartPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    control.Capture = true;
    
}
private void MouseMove(Control control, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_resizing && !_moving)
    {
        UpdateMouseEdgeProperties(control, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        UpdateMouseCursor(control);
    }
    if (_resizing)
    {
        control.Width = (e.X - _cursorStartPoint.X) + _Initwidth;
    }
    else if (_moving)
    {
        
        if (_cursorLast != Cursor.Position)
        {
            count_call ++;
            _cursorLast = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;
            int x = (e.X - _cursorStartPointmove.X);
            int y = (e.Y - _cursorStartPointmove.Y);
            control.Location = new Point(x, y);

            control.Text = x.ToString() + "  " + y.ToString()+"   ||   "+count_call.ToString();
        }
    }
}

private void MouseUp(Control control)
{
    _resizing = false;
    _moving = false;
    control.Capture = false;
    control.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    count_call = 0;
}

}

Ulabel L1 = new Ulabel("label1", Color.Green, 1);
this.Controls.Add(L1);

When I call an object from this class and add a form, the resizing works fine but the moving has problems. The movement of the label is far from the mouse and the label moves between two locations continuously.
enter image description here
Even when the mouse is not moving, it is called and the label is jumped between two location
.
enter image description here
I googled the problem and find this page. Based on that, I added the condition if the mouse cursor moves,if (_cursorLast != Cursor.Position) then change label location. This solved the continuous calling problem, but there is still the problem of jumping between two locations.

Did you try to replace if (_cursorLast != e.Location) to if (_cursorLast != System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position). You're comparing last cursor position to event, but reading the actual position from the different place. Looks confusing.

Thank you for reminding me, I corrected it and the problem of calling continuously was solved, but the problem of jumping between two locations is still there.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614955/drag-and-drop-moving-a-label-in-winforms

You're confusing the coordinate system of the Label (relative to its parent), with that of the mouse; which you've associated with the Label.

I think that if the problem is related to local coordinates, the jump between the two locations should not occur, and, the label should be placed at a fixed distance from the mouse.
Please correct me if I am wrong.

I found a way to avoid this problem, but I don't know how to solve the main problem.
Using Cursor.Position instead of some e position :
e.X, e.Y to Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y
_cursorStartPointmove = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - control.Left, Cursor.Position.Y - control.Top);

...

int x = (Cursor.Position.X - _cursorStartPointmove.X);
int y = (Cursor.Position.Y - _cursorStartPointmove.Y);

